# This is the error i am getting when i use the above command? Can anyone have a solution for this

Tags: python

> > > response.context['latest_question_list']
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: add ur code, or related lines where u get this exception. 'NoneType' object has no attribute... means that you are trying to access an attribute or call a method on something that has the value None.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you didn't get response.
before accessing `response.context['latest_question_list']` you should first try

```
if response:
```

or

```
if response.status_code == 200
```

and then access this.